# Error while using external C++ library with CMake

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

I am trying to use these libraries in my Android project but I am getting many of these similar kind of errors. I have all the tools installed (NDK, LLDB and CMake) but I am still not able to use the library. 
After trying to run the project, all the C++ functions in the header files are unrecognized and compiler shows `Error:error: undefined reference to 'std::string::c_str() const'` and similar other undefined reference errors of C++ functions. Find the complete log of errors [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DF__2p55AWJwseuZcd7MSJk09B7QaNHA/view?usp=sharing).

Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
# For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

include_directories(src/main/cpp/include/ src/main/cpp/include/alglib3 src/main/cpp/include/device src/main/cpp/include/gsl src/main/cpp/include/base)

add_library ( gsl STATIC IMPORTED)
add_library ( gslcblas STATIC IMPORTED)
add_library ( alglib STATIC IMPORTED)
add_library ( crystalport STATIC IMPORTED)


set_target_properties( crystalport PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/libs/armeabi-v7a/libcrystalport_android.a)
set_target_properties( gsl PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/libs/armeabi-v7a/libgsl.a)
set_target_properties( gslcblas PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/libs/armeabi-v7a/libgslcblas.a)
set_target_properties( alglib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/libs/armeabi-v7a/libalglib.a)

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib}
                       alglib
                       crystalport
                       gslcblas
                       gsl
                       )
```

Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "sadboy.circadian"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11 -fexceptions"
            }
        }

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
        }

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

repositories{
    maven {url "https://jitpack.io"}
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: The error you show indicates that you somehow doesn't link with the C++ standard library. If you make a verbose build (set the CMake variable `VERBOSE` to `TRUE`) and rebuild from scratch, you should be able to see exactly what commands and flags are used to build. Use that to attempt to figure out what's wrong. Also take a look at the CMake generation output, what does it say? What compilers do it want to use?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Hello, I am still new with using CMake. I put set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON) in CMakeLists.txt and then did 'cmake .' in AS terminal. I am putting this what I saw in this file due to character limit. [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kVaOvQtBOHLLMTX76RDkfAk2BMf1BkCs/view?usp=sharing). Please help :") I am stuck for very long.

Comment: On the face of it, the imported libraries were not built correctly. Maybe you did not use the same NDK to build **libgsl.a** and the others.

Comment: @AlexCohn Hi, how can determine which NDK was used to build **libgsl.a** and the others. After determining what should I do?

Comment: The best approach is to rebuild these libs yourself, using the latest NDK.

Comment: @AlexCohn get error while building at ':app:externalNativeBuildDebug'. Can you check this [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zampMrkKSGBKJpJmrlQ25k_rJxM9wTh8Dhlj_xSdmKQ/edit?usp=sharing) (open in Google Docs) for error log maybe I can get more insight? See top and bottom, in the middle there are many _undefined reference to_ errors. I can't figure out how to rebuild libs myself. This [issue](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/issues/534) I created for screenshots. Pls help :')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using gnustl_* seems to be able to build:

```
 externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11 -fexceptions"
                arguments "-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static"
            }
        }
```

Also using extern "C" to avoid runtime error in my native-lib.cpp file.